# Aligning rotated xticklabels with their respective xticks

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis-labels

Check the x axis of the figure below. How can I move the labels a bit to the left so that they align with their respective ticks?

I'm rotating the labels using:

```
ax.set_xticks(xlabels_positions)
ax.set_xticklabels(xlabels, rotation=45)
```

But, as you can see, the rotation is centered on the middle of the text labels. Which makes it look like they are shifted to the right.

I've tried using this instead:

```
ax.set_xticklabels(xlabels, rotation=45, rotation_mode="anchor")
```

... but it doesn't do what I wished for. And `"anchor"` seems to be the only value allowed for the `rotation_mode` parameter.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 295, accepted):

You can set the horizontal alignment of ticklabels, see the example below. If you imagine a rectangular box around the rotated label, which side of the rectangle do you want to be aligned with the tickpoint?

Given your description, you want: ha='right'

```
n=5

x = np.arange(n)
y = np.sin(np.linspace(-3,3,n))
xlabels = ['Ticklabel %i' % i for i in range(n)]

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,3, figsize=(12,3))

ha = ['right', 'center', 'left']

for n, ax in enumerate(axs):
    ax.plot(x,y, 'o-')
    ax.set_title(ha[n])
    ax.set_xticks(x)
    ax.set_xticklabels(xlabels, rotation=40, ha=ha[n])
```

[image]

Comment: You can also use `xlabels = ax.get_xticklabels()` if you just want to use the existing labels.

Comment: I prefer something like `for ax, ha_ in zip(axes, ha):` and `ha=ha_`

Answer (score 71):

`ha='right'` is not enough to **visually** align labels with ticks:

- For `rotation=45`, use **both** `ha='right'` and `rotation_mode='anchor'`
- For other angles, use a `ScaledTranslation()` instead

---

### [`rotation_mode='anchor'`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text.set_rotation_mode)

If the rotation angle is roughly 45°, combine `ha='right'` with `rotation_mode='anchor'`:

```py
ax.set_xticks(ticks)
ax.set_xticklabels(labels, rotation=45, ha='right', rotation_mode='anchor')
```

Or in matplotlib 3.5.0+, [set ticks and labels at once](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70272740/13138364):

```py
ax.set_xticks(ticks, labels, rotation=45, ha='right', rotation_mode='anchor')
```

[image: anchored rotation]

---

### [`ScaledTranslation()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14852821/aligning-rotated-xticklabels-with-their-respective-xticks/67459618#67459618)

If the rotation angle is more extreme (e.g., 70°) or you just want more fine-grained control, anchoring won't work well. Instead, [apply a linear transform](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49449590/13138364):

```py
ax.set_xticks(ticks)
ax.set_xticklabels(labels, rotation=70)

# create -5pt offset in x direction
from matplotlib.transforms import ScaledTranslation
dx, dy = -5, 0
offset = ScaledTranslation(dx / fig.dpi, dy / fig.dpi, fig.dpi_scale_trans)

# apply offset to all xticklabels
for label in ax.xaxis.get_majorticklabels():
    label.set_transform(label.get_transform() + offset)
```

[image: scaled translation]

Answer (score 24):

Rotating the labels is certainly possible. Note though that doing so reduces the readability of the text. One alternative is to alternate label positions using a code like this:

```
import numpy as np
n=5

x = np.arange(n)
y = np.sin(np.linspace(-3,3,n))
xlabels = ['Long ticklabel %i' % i for i in range(n)]


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x,y, 'o-')
ax.set_xticks(x)
labels = ax.set_xticklabels(xlabels)
for i, label in enumerate(labels):
    label.set_y(label.get_position()[1] - (i % 2) * 0.075)
```

[image]

For more background and alternatives, see [this post on my blog](https://gorelik.net/2017/11/23/how-to-make-a-graph-less-readable-rotate-the-text-labels/)

Answer (score 15):

An easy, loop-free alternative is to use the `horizontalalignment` Text property as a keyword argument to `xticks`[1]. In the below, at the commented line, I've forced the `xticks` alignment to be "right".

```
n=5
x = np.arange(n)
y = np.sin(np.linspace(-3,3,n))
xlabels = ['Long ticklabel %i' % i for i in range(n)]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x,y, 'o-')

plt.xticks(
        [0,1,2,3,4],
        ["this label extends way past the figure's left boundary",
        "bad motorfinger", "green", "in the age of octopus diplomacy", "x"], 
        rotation=45,
        horizontalalignment="right")    # here
plt.show()
```

(`yticks` already aligns the right edge with the tick by default, but for `xticks` the default appears to be "center".)

[1] You find that described in the [xticks documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html) if you search for the phrase "Text properties".

Answer (score 14):

I am clearly late but there is an official example which uses

```py
plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, ha="right", rotation_mode="anchor")
```

to rotate the labels while keeping them correctly aligned with the ticks, which is both clean and easy.

See: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/image_annotated_heatmap.html

Comment: there is no setp() function. Use 
        ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, ha="right", rotation_mode="anchor")

Comment: @Keith The `setp` function exists. https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.setp.html

Comment: Hmm Well I got an error saying that it did not. Perhaps a version issue

Comment: My guess is that you tried `ax.setp` instead of `plt.setp`.

Answer (score 1):

@tdy's answer is close to perfect. I think a quicker way to get the labels to look nice is to use a combination of *all three* of the following settings:

- `ha='right'`
- `va='top'`
- `rotation_mode='anchor'`

This way, there is no need for working with the `ScaledTranslation`. This seems to work well with all angles of rotation.

```py
ax.set_xticklabels(labels, rotation=30, ha='right', va='top', rotation_mode='anchor')
``
```