# Why set_xticks doesn't set the labels of ticks?

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = range(1, 7)
y = (220, 300, 300, 290, 320, 315)

def test(axes):
    axes.bar(x, y)
    axes.set_xticks(x, [i+100 for i in x])

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)
test(ax1)
test(ax2)
```

[image]

I am expecting the xlabs as `101, 102 ...`
However, if i switch to use `plt.xticks(x, [i+100 for i in x])` and rewrite the function explicitly, it works.

Comment: My guess is because in your code set_xticks is getting a generator object, not a list. Try `list([i+100 for i in x)]` instead.

Comment: @rabs there is no generator involved, they are both lists, I am using python 2

Answer (score 147, accepted):

[`.set_xticks()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticks.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticks) on the axes will set the locations and [`set_xticklabels()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticklabels.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticklabels) will set the displayed text.

```
def test(axes):
    axes.bar(x,y)
    axes.set_xticks(x)
    axes.set_xticklabels([i+100 for i in x])
```

[image]

Comment: @RichardRast and it's still appears to be weird.

Comment: plt.xticks(position, label) works while set_xticks on axis like subplots doesnt and one needs another call set_xticklabels. i call bad api on pyplot

Comment: `axes.set_xticklabels` did the trick

Comment: NB : axes can be accessed with `plt.gca()`.

Comment: @SkippyleGrandGourou: but if I do `plt.gca().set_xticks(...)` it has no effect?

Comment: Ah my problem was I called `xscale` after which blew away the ticks

Answer (score 10):

Another function that might be useful, if you don't want labels for every (or even any) tick is `axes.tick_params`.

```
def test(axes):
    axes.tick_params(axis='x',which='minor',direction='out',bottom=True,length=5)
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

#### New in matplotlib 3.5.0

[`ax.set_xticks`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticks.html) now accepts a `labels` param to set ticks and labels simultaneously:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(x, y)
ax.set_xticks(x, labels=[i + 100 for i in x])
#                ^^^^^^
```

[image: ticklabels changed with labels param]

Since changing labels usually requires changing ticks, the `labels` param has been added to all relevant tick functions for convenience:

- `ax.xaxis.set_ticks(..., labels=...)`
- `ax.yaxis.set_ticks(..., labels=...)`
- `ax.set_xticks(..., labels=...)`
- `ax.set_yticks(..., labels=...)`

Comment: What if you're just using the plt.foo commands and don't have an ax object?

Comment: @JosephGarvin Then you can get the ax object manually via `ax = plt.gca()`

Comment: added a new comment there, issue was I called xscale after