# Matplotlib ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, matplotlib

When I use the following code below to make a plot, in which I assign customized values to the x axis and set `xlim`, it works out.

```
x = np.array([0,1,2,3])
y = np.array([0.650, 0.660, 0.675, 0.685])
customized_x = np.array([3, 4, 5, 6])
plt.xticks(x, customized_x)
plt.xlim(2, 3)
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

However, because I want to make a few more plots together, when I use subplot instead, it pops out at the line `ax1.set_xticks(x, customized_x)`:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=[6.0, 9.0])
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

x = np.array([0,1,2,3])
y = np.array([0.650, 0.660, 0.675, 0.685])
customized_x = np.array([3, 4, 5, 6])
ax1.set_xticks(x, customized_x)
ax1.set_xlim(2, 3)
ax1.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

Error obtained:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Although 
I can avoid the issue by not using subplots, I am still wondering what's wrong with subplots?

**EDIT**

I find a [solution to the similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21910986/why-set-xticks-doesnt-set-the-labels-of-ticks). Sorry for the repetition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to use `set_xticks` mistakenly. From `matplotlib` documentation:

> Axes.set_xticks(self, ticks, minor=False)¶

This is because `Axes.set_xticks` has different arguments, compared to `plt.xticks`. The code tries to evaluate `customized_x` as the `minor` parameter.

I think what you need is `Axes.set_xticklabels`: see [the documentation here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticklabels.html)