# Moving matplotlib xticklabels by pixel value

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

How can I move tick labels by a few pixels?

In my case, I want to move the *This is class #N*-labels on the X-axis to the right by a few pixels.

I am [aware of the](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46652187/1144382) `horizontalalign`/`ha` values `right`, `center`, and `left`; but I want to "improve" the looks of the `right` alignment.

Take the following example which will produce the plot shown below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

categories = ['This is class #{}'.format(n) for n in range(10)]
data = {
    'Value': [categories[np.random.randint(10)] for _ in range(100)], 
    'id': [1000+i for i in range(100)]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

ax = df.Value.value_counts().sort_index().plot(kind='bar', rot=45)
plt.xticks(ha='right')
```

Results in:

[image]

I think, subjectively, that the plot would look better if the labels were translated to the right so that the tick were placed over the "#". In other words, a "middle ground" between the `right` and `center` alignment options.

**Side notes**:

I'm using pandas, but I believe that is irrelevant to the issue, as it's using matplotlib to do its plotting anyway.

The `plt.xticks()` method is used for simplicity, I could just as well use `ax.set_xticklabels()`, but I don't need to rewrite the label texts, and AFAIK there is no shortcut to set the horizontal alignment without also copying the existing labels into with `ax.set_xticklabels(labels, **more_options)`, as `ha` is not a valid [key in matplotlib 2](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params.html)'s `ax.xaxis.set_tick_params()`-method.

I'm aware of pandas' `Series.hist()`-method, but I think the `Series.value_counts().plot(kind='bar')` looks prettier when I have few categories and want the number of bars to be the same as number of categories.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to move the ticklabels by a few pixels you may add a translation to their transformation chain. E.g. to move by 20 pixels to the right, use

```
import matplotlib.transforms as mtrans
# ...
trans = mtrans.Affine2D().translate(20, 0)
for t in ax.get_xticklabels():
    t.set_transform(t.get_transform()+trans)
```

If course the number of pixels that you need to shift in order for the #-sign to be under the tickmark is not a priori clear - that needs to be found out via trial and error. Or maybe you have a different hint on by how much you want to shift in what other units.

Here is the complete example,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.transforms as mtrans

categories = ['This is class #{}'.format(n) for n in range(10)]
data = {
    'Value': [categories[np.random.randint(10)] for _ in range(100)], 
    'id': [1000+i for i in range(100)]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

ax = df.Value.value_counts().sort_index().plot(kind='bar', rot=45)
plt.xticks(ha='right')

trans = mtrans.Affine2D().translate(20, 0)
for t in ax.get_xticklabels():
    t.set_transform(t.get_transform()+trans)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

producing

[image]

Comment: This worked perfectly as described. Nice answer with complete example and image.

Comment: For some reason, I get the expected result in-line, but if I use "savefig", the saved image does not have the expected translation.