# Matplotlib: Setting xaxis tick labels at specific y-intercept but x-axis and ticks at y=0

Tags: python, matplotlib

As title, I have multiple subplots and would like to have the x-axis tick labels shown at y=-1 (all my subplots have ylimits (-1.1 to 1.1), while the x-axis line and ticks shown at y=0. My current redacted code is as follows:

```
while x < 10: 
    plt.add_subplot(10,1,x).yaxis.tick_right()
    plt.subplot(10,1,x).spines['bottom'].set_position('zero')
    plt.subplot(10,1,x).spines['bottom'].set_color('xkcd:light grey')
    plt.subplot(10,1,x).set_facecolor('xkcd:dark grey')
    plt.tick_params(axis='x', direction='out', labelbottom='on', color='xkcd:light grey', labelcolor='xkcd:light grey')
    plt.plot()
    plt.ylim(-1.1,1.1)

    x+=1

plt.show()
```

Current example of a subplot looks like this:

[image]

Comment: You could use `Axes.tick_params('x', pad=100)` to create padding above the x-axis labels, pushing them down to `y=-1`. Adjust the padding value until you find the position you want.

Comment: To get better answers, please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) including the expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's rather unusual to set the ticklabel position in data coordinates. But it's still possible. Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48326151/moving-matplotlib-xticklabels-by-pixel-value) you may use a transform to shift the labels. Here we would first shift them by 1 data unit and then apply the usual transform.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(42)
import matplotlib.transforms as mtrans

x = np.linspace(2013.6,2018.4)
y = np.cumsum(np.random.randn(50))/12.+0.3

ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.yaxis.tick_right()
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('zero')
ax.spines['bottom'].set_color('xkcd:light grey')
ax.set_facecolor('xkcd:dark grey')
ax.tick_params(axis='x', direction='out', labelbottom=True, pad=0, 
               color='xkcd:light grey', labelcolor='xkcd:light grey')
ax.plot(x,y)
ax.set_ylim(-1.1,1.1)


trans = mtrans.Affine2D().translate(0,-1.)
for t in ax.get_xticklabels():
    t.set_transform(trans + t.get_transform())

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Usually this can be set by [`set_position`](https://matplotlib.org/api/spines_api.html#matplotlib.spines.Spine.set_position), and specifying '**data**':

```
plt.subplot(10,1,x).spines['bottom'].set_position(('data', -1))
```

> ‘**data**’ : place the spine at the specified data coordinate.

↳ [matplotlib.spines | set_position](https://matplotlib.org/api/spines_api.html#matplotlib.spines.Spine.set_position)

Comment: This brings the whole axis (including the ticks) down to -1. Is there a way to just bring the tick labels (ie the dates in this case) down to y=-1?

Comment: @Singapore123 : Sure there’s a way, although I’m confused by what you are asking apparently. Maybe post an example screenshot of how you want it to look. Currently when I try your code I just get a grey bar, so more of your code displaying data might be helpful as well.