# Using 'set_x' to move xticklabel to right

Tags: python, matplotlib

Here is an example plot along with a dataset.

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (5,5))
x_data = np.arange(0,5,1)
y_data = [10,20,4,1,28]
x_labels = ['Val1', 'Val2', 'A Lengthy', "Unexpected", 'Val5']
ax.bar(x_data, y_data, tick_label = x_labels)
```

[image]

I want to move the xticklabel `Unexpected` a little to the right. So I thought of using this

```py
for val in ax.get_xticklabels():
    if val.get_text() == "Unexpected":
        x,y = val.get_position()
        print(f'Old Position [{x},{y}]')
        val.set_y(-0.03)
        val.set_x(x + 0.25)
        x,y = val.get_position()
        print(f'New Position [{x},{y}]')
```

Here is the outcome

[image]

The label moves downwards but not towards the right.

I want to know why is `set_x` not working as expected. Is there anything overriding it? I got a [solution online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48326151/moving-matplotlib-xticklabels-by-pixel-value) that uses `transforms`. Is that overriding the `set_x` command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your question is on why `set_x` is not working, you can refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28615887/how-to-move-a-tick-label-in-matplotlib) and response from `explorerDude` on how to use it.

However, if you are trying to get the readability better, a simple solution would be to use `rotation` of the axis by some degrees.

But, if you require only the `Unexpected` label to be lower, the below code using `set_transform` should do the trick... Use `dx` and `dy` to move the label by as many pixels as you need.

**Code**

```
import matplotlib.transforms as trns

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (5,5))
x_data = np.arange(0,5,1)
y_data = [10,20,4,1,28]
x_labels = ['Val1', 'Val2', 'A Lengthy', "Unexpected", 'Val5']
ax.bar(x_data, y_data, tick_label = x_labels)

dx = 10/72.; dy = -10/72. 
offset = trns.ScaledTranslation(dx, dy, fig.dpi_scale_trans)

for val in ax.get_xticklabels():
    if val.get_text() == "Unexpected":
        x,y = val.get_position()
        val.set_transform(val.get_transform() + offset)
        x,y = val.get_position()
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the link to why `set_x` didn't work. I explored a little more and will add a more detailed answer to why `set_x` didn't work

Comment: Also for transform, we could use the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48326151/moving-matplotlib-xticklabels-by-pixel-value) as it only uses `x` and `y` values and not that `fig.dpi_scale_trans`

Comment: Nice, just to clarify I think that the question is asking exactly what you are answering in your first sentence. The question states quite clearly that the solution to the problem is in the other linked post and just asks why is `set_x` overriden.

Answer (score 0):

As in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33688795/16891669) provided by *@Redox*, the reason is that the call to `set_x` is overriden when the rendering is done. 
It can be seen by making some changes to the custom set_x made by *@explorerDude* as shown in the link.

```py
import types

SHIFT = 0.1 # Data coordinates
def func(self, x):
    print("set_x called with x =", x)
    mlt.text.Text.set_x(self, x + SHIFT)

for label in ax.xaxis.get_majorticklabels():
    if label.get_text() == "Unexpected":
        label.set_x = types.MethodType( lambda self,x: func(self, x), label)
        print("mycall")
```

It's output

```
mycall
set_x called with x = 3
set_x called with x = 3
set_x called with x = 3
set_x called with x = 3
set_x called with x = 3
set_x called with x = 3
set_x called with x = 3
set_x called with x = 3
set_x called with x = 3
set_x called with x = 3
```

As seen set_x is called afterwards internally. **It's argument is 3 and is calculated internally. So no matter what we write to set_x, it's overriden.**

However as seen in func, `matplotlib.text.Text.set_x` is called with `x+SHIFT` which changes the position in every call and the final result is as below.

[image]

However overriding internal functions seems dangerous and instead using `transform` as in @Redox's answer or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48326151/moving-matplotlib-xticklabels-by-pixel-value) is better