# matplotlib：after rotate the x_label，how to keep the tail of x_label aligned to the x_tick

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

[image]

could someone give me the solution about how to keep the tail of x_label aligned to the x_tick, thanks a lot!

Comment: labels should have a property "horizontalalignment", try using that. In this case you wanna set it to "right". But without seeing your code we can't make more detailed suggestions.

Comment: [An example of Harpe's suggestion.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14854007/8881141)

Comment: thank Mr.T and Harpe a lot, the problem is fixed.