# seaborn x label date format align day of week abbreviation

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, date-format

How can I align the day of week abbreviations to be on the same level? Currently, it is alternating.

[image: ta-]

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns; sns.set()

df = pd.DataFrame({'dt':['2020-01-01', '2020-01-02', '2020-01-03', '2020-01-04'], 'foo':[10, 15, 8, 13]})
df['dt'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dt'])
display(df)

ax = sns.lineplot(x='dt', y='foo', data=df)

import matplotlib.dates as mdates
date_form = DateFormatter("%a %d-%m")
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(date_form)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator(interval=1))
plt.xticks(rotation=90, horizontalalignment='center', fontsize=28)
''
```

Comment: I'm not sure . but does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14852821/aligning-rotated-xticklabels-with-their-respective-xticks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to align the start of the tick labels would be to rotate the other way around:

```py
plt.xticks(rotation=-90, ha='center', fontsize=28)
```

[image: rotated clockwise]

Alternatively, the tick labels can be vertically aligned to the bottom, but then they need to be shifted down. The exact distance depends on font, fontsize and text length:

```py
plt.xticks(rotation=90, ha='center', va='bottom', fontsize=28)
plt.tick_params(axis='x', which='major', pad=150)
```

[image: rotated anti clockwise]

Still another option is to choose a monospace font. Note that with a usual font, a 'W' takes up much more space than an 'i'. If such a monospace font is desired, "courier new" is one of best-looking options.

```py
plt.xticks(rotation=90, horizontalalignment='center', fontsize=28, family=['courier new', 'monospace'])
```

[image: monospace font]

Comment: But they are still jumping around. Now on the other side. Is it possible to simply use 2 characters?

Comment: Another option is using a monospaced font. Having only two characters won't change that a 'W' is wider in the usual proportional fonts.

Comment: Indeed. But the look of the monospaced font also doesn't make me really happy. Do you know if justification (just like in MS Word) would work for the axis?

Comment: As far as I know, matplotlib text doesn't support such an option. The most advanced text options are in `plt.annotate` which also doesn't seem to consider such type of alignment.