# Formatting axis label in a subplot with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, axis-labels

so, I'm stuck with two problem in formatting axis labels with matplotlib.
I made a subplot of some x-y data changing axis labels. Actually those data are unix timestamp floating points which I use to make a linear fit. Then I formatted them in a more human readable way with time and datetime to use as labels for the plot. So far I'm successfull but...I have two problems:

- first of all labels (both on x and y axis) are overlapping
- Then on x axis, labels seems to be mooved to the right instead of matching the point's line (even if they are rotated)

This is a view of the plot:

[image: ![enter image description here]

My code is the following:

```
def fit_one(x,y,lx,ly):
    par = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
    q,m = np.polyfit(x, y, 1, cov=True)
    fit_fn=np.poly1d(par)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,15))
    
    ax.set_xticks(x)
    ax.set_xticklabels(lx, rotation=60)
    ax.set_yticks(y)
    ax.set_yticklabels(ly)
    ax.set_ylabel('gtu_time', fontsize = 12)
    ax.set_xlabel('entry_time',fontsize = 12)
    ax.plot(x,y,'k*',label='data')
    ax.plot(x,fit_fn(x),color='red', label='fit')
    #fig.tight_layout()

    fig.savefig('data_fit.pdf')
    #plt.xlim((1571512436,1609826672))
    plt.show()
    chi_squared = np.sum((np.polyval(par, x) - y) ** 2)
    print '\n\n'
    print 'Chi2   =    %.3f' % chi_squared  
    print 'p0     =    %.9f     +/- %.9f' % (q[1], np.sqrt(m[1][1]))
    print 'p1     =    %.9f     +/- %.9f' % (q[0], np.sqrt(m[0][0]))
    print '\n\n', par
```

Moreover I would like to understand why if I add `loc='right'` on the `ax.set_xlabel('entry_time',fontsize = 12)` line I get the following error:

> AttributeError: Unknown property loc

which I really don't understand while it is on the matplotlib documentation.

Any advices on how to solve those problems?
Thanks!

Comment: No problem on my end with `ax.set_xlabel('entry_time',fontsize = 12, loc="right")`. Matplotlib 3.3.3 Python 3.8

Comment: As for their alignment, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14852821/8881141). They are aligned to their center.

Comment: There is no way to print all labels with the font size to the precise location without overlapping. you probably want to delete some label points (without deleting data points)

Comment: `loc=` possibly doesn't work in older versions of matplotlib. You might want to upgrade to the latest. Also, Python 2 has been fully substituted to Python 3 nowadays. If possible, you really should upgrade.