# How to annotate line with text rotated along the line in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to add an annotation between 2 points with text at the middle and rotate the text to align with the line.
Current example does not rotate as expected:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def ann_distance(ax,xyfrom,xyto,text=None):
    midx = (xyto[0]+xyfrom[0])/2
    midy = (xyto[1]+xyfrom[1])/2
    if text is None:
        text = str(np.sqrt( (xyfrom[0]-xyto[0])**2 + (xyfrom[1]-xyto[1])**2 ))

    ax.annotate("",xyfrom,xyto,arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='<->'))
    p1 = ax.transData.transform_point((xyfrom[0], xyfrom[1]))
    p2 = ax.transData.transform_point((xyto[0], xyto[1]))
    rotn = np.degrees(np.arctan2(p2[1]-p1[1], p2[0]-p1[0]))
    ax.text(midx,midy,text,ha='center', va='bottom',rotation=rotn,fontsize=16)
    return

x = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,100)

width = 800
height = 600

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x,np.sin(x))
ann_distance(plt.gca(),[np.pi/2,1],[2*np.pi,0],'$sample$')
plt.show()
```

Current output:
[image]

Comment: What are the values of `p1` and `p2`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add two [`text`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/text_api.html) params to make the text rotation match the line:

1. **`transform_rotates_text=True`** rotates the text relative to the figure scales
2. **`rotation_mode='anchor'`** [anchors the rotation relative to `va` and `ha`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67459618/13138364)

```
dx = xyto[0] - xyfrom[0]
dy = xyto[1] - xyfrom[1]
rotn = np.degrees(np.arctan2(dy, dx)) # not the transformed p2 and p1

ax.text(midx, midy, text, ha='center', va='bottom', fontsize=16,
        rotation=rotn, rotation_mode='anchor', transform_rotates_text=True)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it works fine. any param to move the text a little bit far from the line? current text will overlap with the line if add background color to the text.

Comment: @lucky1928 Not that I know of, especially when using a background color. If there's no background, one workaround is to add a newline to the text and adjust the `linespacing` param: `ax.text(midx, midy, f'{text}\n', ha='center', va='bottom', rotation=rotn, rotation_mode='anchor', transform_rotates_text=True, linespacing=0.5)`